# .htaccess redirect if root, index.php, not file or not directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently I have a controller that handles requests (using friendly URLs). To redirect to this controller I use the following .htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __controller.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I then have an **index.php** that redirects to /home which is the home page (I force this so the home page also uses the controller):

```
<?php
header('Location: home', true, 301);
exit();
?>
```

However, I also want it to send to this controller if the file is index.php or if it's the root domain (as I no longer want the home page to be www.test.com/home but rather just www.test.com), so each of the following will go through the controller:

www.test.com/friendly-url/123/post-topic (currently works)

But also:

www.test.com/index.php AND
www.test.com

Obviously the last 2 conditions won't work at the moment as the index.php file exists so the .htaccess won't send it through the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^index.php$ /home [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ __controller.php?p=home [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __controller.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Are you looking for this ?

Then you don't need the PHP redirection

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (?!^index\.php/?$)^(.+)$ __controller.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```